# Use component lazy loading in multi components angular?

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-module

I have Three components (**NavbarComponent** , **IndexComponent** , **PoweredComponent** ) so I use lazy loading I need use components in multi components ,I don't know how to declare the component for using it in the lazy module. I'll show you some of the relevant parts of the different files:

1. NavbarComponent

   **navbar.module.ts**

```
  declarations: [NavbarComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [NavbarComponent]
})
```

2. IndexComponent

   **Index.module.ts**

```
  declarations: [IndexComponent ,NavbarComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IndexRoutingModule,
  ],
})
```

**index.component.html**

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div>...</div>
```

in index show navbar

[image: index.component.html]

3. PoweredComponent

   **powered.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [PoweredComponent,NavbarComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PoweredRoutingModule,
  ], 
})
```

**powered.component.html**

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
<div>...</div>
```

in `powered.component.html` no show navbar

> issue `<app-navbar></app-navbar>` not dispaly in multi components can show jsut in index components

Pleas help me???

Thank's to read!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index.module.ts

```
  declarations: [IndexComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IndexRoutingModule,
    NavbarModule
  ],
})
```

powered.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [PoweredComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PoweredRoutingModule,
    NavbarModule
  ], 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a Component (using `declarations`) in more than one NgModule.
In your situation, as your `NavbarModule` exports the `NavBarComponent`, you just need to import the module in the `PoweredModule` and `IndexModule` to make the Component available in these modules.

So for `IndexModule` as an example :

```
 declarations: [IndexComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IndexRoutingModule,
    NavbarModule
  ],
})
```